# How can I call a Perl function from a shell script?

Tags: perl, scripting

I have written a library in Perl that contains a certain function, that returns information about a server as a character string. Can I call this function from a shell directly?

My boss asks "Can you call it from a shell directly for the time being?" Because he said that, I think I should be able to do it, but how do I do it?

Comment: Hmm I wonder if this is really a valuable question if nobody fixes the wording...

Answer (score 10):

```
perl -MServerlib=server_information -e 'print server_information()'
```

Is another way to do this, but only if Serverlib exports `server_information` sub. If it doesn't, you would need to do the below instead:

```
perl -MServerlib -e 'print MServerlib::server_information()'
```

Comment: this sounds more like what the OP is being requested to do.

Comment: +1, but this also should include an example of using backticks to capture the output from that print in a variable for use in the shell script.

Answer (score 7):

As perl's command line arguments are a bit inscrutable, I'd wrap it in a simpler perl script that calls the function. For example, create a script `serverinfo` which contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require 'library.pl';
say library::getServerInformation();
```

then run:

```
chmod u+x serverinfo
```

The advantage of doing it this way is the output and arguments of the script can be corrected if the function itself changes. A command line script like this can be thought of as an API, which shouldn't change when the implementation changes.